# Passing values into variable using spring annotation

Tags: java, spring

I am new at Spring technology. I have a small doubt. I learned that we can pass the value in a list of a class using `beans.xml` file as below

```
    <bean id="Hello" class="mywork.Hello">
    <property name="myList">
        <list>
            <value>India</value>
            <value>Pakistan</value>
            <value>Nepal</value>
            <value>China</value>
        </list>
   </property>
   </bean>
```

And I also found that we use annotation that will do same work as `xml` file.
I am looking for a substitute annotation to use for passing this value into my class.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Look for information about the `@Value` annotation ;)

Comment: Why annotation ? You can directly initialize your class fields with given  values which you want to set through annotation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can inject a list into your class with either @Value or @Resource annotation. Firstly, you need to declare the util schema in your spring xml

```
<beans ....
xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
xsi:schemaLocation="....
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd">
```

1. Using @Value

In the xml, declare the properties file location. Something like this:

```
<util:properties id="systemPropertyLookup" location="classpath:system.properties"/>
```

Then put your string array definition into system.properties file:

```
my.country.list=India,Pakistan,Nepal,China
```

Finally, inject the array into your list of Hello class like below:

```
@Value("${my.country.list}")
private List<String> myList;
```

2. Using @Resource

In the xml, declare your list:

```
<util:list id="myCountryList" value-type="java.lang.String">
    <value>India</value>
    <value>Pakistan</value>
    <value>Nepal</value>
    <value>China</value>
</util:list>
```

Then inject into your class:

```
@Resource(name="myCountryList")
private List<String> myList;
```